# MSIX packaged application will always ask for firewall rule when it updates

Tags: msix

I have an MSIX application that is being built in the pipeline but each time the application updates and starts it will ask for firewall rule to be added as soon as it makes a call to some http API.

If I go to firewall and check for all previous rules referencing this application it becomes clear why this is happening. So for instance I now have around 20 rules just from testing today and they are all tied to program and look something like this:

C:\program files\windowsapps{guid*}*{app_version**}*{another_uniqueIdentifier***}\MyApplication.exe

- (*) This is drawn from manifest -> identity -> name
- (**) There is a powershell script that updates package.appxmanifest version with build number from the pipeline
- (***) I am not sure where this comes from

So obviously everytime I build a new version of the application it will receive this value and when I update and run it, firewall will think it is a new application. I doubt this is by design as Firewall would get clogged with firewall rules very soon in some instances where applications receive a lot of new updates.

**What am I missing here?**

My application (*.wapproj targeting the actual application) is being built from the Azure DevOps pipeline and these are `msbuild` parameters I use:

```
/p:ApplicationVersion=$(Build.BuildNumber) 
/p:Version=$(Build.BuildNumber) 
/p:AllowUnsafeBlocks=true 
/p:SelfContained=false 
/p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=true 
/p:PackageCertificateThumbprint="$(Thumbprint)" 
/p:AppxPackageSigningTimestampServerUrl="http://timestamp.digicert.com" 
/p:AppxPackageSigningTimestampDigestAlgorithm="SHA256" 
/p:AppInstallerUri="https://ourlocal.server.com/Clients/MyApplication/"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to bypass firewall rules by adding to your package.appxmanifest file following entries:

```
<Extensions>
    <desktop2:Extension Category="windows.firewallRules">
      <desktop2:FirewallRules Executable="your-exe-name">
        <desktop2:Rule Direction="out" IPProtocol="TCP" LocalPortMin="80" LocalPortMax="80" Profile="all"/>
```

where desktop2 is declared inside 'Package' tag as

```
xmlns:desktop2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10/2"
```

You can add multiple rules, like another one for 443 if you access some https.